# What is causing yellow spots with 'hair growth' on the underside of the leaves on my tree?

Tags: trees, diagnosis

I've slowly been bringing this tree back from some devastating summers 5 years ago where several large branches died.  I've been diligent about pruning and feeding.

For lack of a better description, the leaves now have holes along the edges, burn marks, and yellow spots that have "hair-like" growth on the underside.

It's a type of apple tree that has had several large branches die or break several years ago and many small branches die. Years ago it would flower in the spring but it hasn't flowered in at least 4 years since it had all the damage.

We live outside New York City on Long Island if that matters.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hj7Uj.jpg) are some pictures in addition to the photo below.

[image]

Comment: This looks like an elderly crab apple or apple tree that has suffered some severe structural damage in the past.(see the other pictures for the damage)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you might be dealing with Apple Rust disease. [Apple Rust Disease](http://www.hort.uconn.edu/ipm/homegrnd/htms/20aprust.htm) Please read this link and let us know if this sounds correct.  This link also has species vulnerability notes and what to spray with to prevent this disease.  I don't think there is anything to 'cure' it now.  The host plant are junipers...have any nearby?

Comment: Thank you stormy.  That looks like the problem.  We do have a cedar tree on our property and I searched for similar terms and found these additional articles and pictures that match our problem:
http://www.extension.umn.edu/garden/yard-garden/trees-shrubs/cedar-apple-rust-and-gymnosporangium-rusts/
http://www.treehelp.com/cedar-apple-rust/
http://homeguides.sfgate.com/treat-cedar-apple-rust-48649.html

Most of what I've been reading says that I need to spray in the spring so I'm not sure what to do now.  Also, the leaves have holes along the edges which look like some form of insect problem.

Comment: Nice one, stormy! Do you have CAR up where you live?

Comment: What is CAR?? Thanks by the way...!

Comment: mjbeller...what have you been using for fertilizer?  If you are using a high Nitrogen fertilizer (higher in percentage relative to P and K) and/or the tree is getting a lot of Nitrogen from the lawn fertilizer, this would promote vegetative growth (as well as fungus) and reduce reproductive growth. I'd also look for insects that are making a home in the bark/lichen/moss of this tree.  How badly do you want to keep this tree?  How old is it in your guesstimation?

Comment: Was that a pop-quiz? Grin! CAR, cedar-apple-rust!

Comment: We must have it here.  I've seen samples in seminars but I don't remember running into this problem much.